# Getting an error when configuring "serve modules without publishing"

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I have recently configured my tomcat 6.0 with "*serve modules without publishing*" option, in order to avoid the end of the http session when I perform a hot code replacement. Since then I'm having the next error when starting the server:

`GRAVE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'K' (code 75) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,1,"jndi:/localhost/projectX/WEB-INF/wsdl/.svn/prop-base/WSprojectXService_schema1.xsd.svn-base"]
XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'K' (code 75) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,1,"jndi:/localhost/projectX/WEB-INF/wsdl/.svn/prop-base/WSprojectXService_schema1.xsd.svn-base"]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.wrapException(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.SDDocumentImpl.create(SDDocumentImpl.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.categoriseMetadata(EndpointFactory.java:413)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:318)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:337)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:239)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'K' (code 75) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,1,"jndi:/localhost/projectX/WEB-INF/wsdl/.svn/prop-base/WSprojectXService_schema1.xsd.svn-base"]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:51)
    ... 25 more`

This error never happened before without the "*serve modules without publishing*" option. It seems is trying to parse a svn inner file, and it's getting a parsing exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The file

.svn/prop-base/WSprojectXService_schema1.xsd.svn-base

should not be exported to tomcat.

Upgrade to latest versions of subversion. It only has a .svn folder (in the oldest parent folder) and not one for each subfolder (which is why you're exporting the .svn subfolder).

You can try to tell eclipse not to export .svn subfolders but I do not know how to do that ...

Victor.